# How to detect/select elements created from JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to `Show-Hide` an element by clicking on an element that was created from JS code. But for some reason `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` not work to select these HTML elements. (Please check the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vy09nnco/)

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="toShow">Hello World!</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Creating the `<p>` element (which will be used to Show-Hide) and `appending` to the container `div`:

```
var code = '<p class="click-me">Click Me!</p>';
$('#container').append(code);
```

Here is the complete JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var code = '<p class="click-me">Click Me!</p>';     
    var divToShow = document.getElementById('toShow');
    var clickMeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('click-me'); // Here is the problem
    var isOpenedClass = 'isOpened';
    var formIsClosed = true;

    $(clickMeDiv).click(function() {
        $(divToShow).toggleClass(isOpenedClass);
        formIsClosed = false;
    });
    $(clickMeDiv).click(function() {
        if (formIsClosed) {
            $(divToShow).removeClass(isOpenedClass);
        }
        formIsClosed = true;
    })      
    $('#container').append(code);    
});
```

When I use another element to Show-Hide, it works good (example: http://jsfiddle.net/vy09nnco/1/), that is why the problem it's only by selecting the created code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The element is not in the document yet see the difference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vy09nnco/3/).

Comment: If you use DOM objects instead of innerhtml for creating the new elements you then have a direct reference to the element and can then attach event listeners directly.

Comment: You are trying to add a listener before the object exists in the DOM, just append it first, or create the listeners on the append callback.

Comment: Thanks everyone people! You are right, the problem was in the order of the functions!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you're creating the element after the page loads so it's not in the DOM thus does not have a listener attached to it. You can add an event listener to the `body` (or a parent element or something) to look for the newly created element:

```
$("body").on("click", clickMeDiv, function() {
```

instead of

```
$(clickMeDiv).click(function() {
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vy09nnco/2/)

Since you're using Jquery anyways there really isnt a reason to use vanilla Javascript. You can do soemthing like this with a lot less code:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vy09nnco/5/)

Comment: but why now by clicking on the shown div (`toShow`) it hide it too?

Comment: It works good! Thanks for your time. Please, Can you explain me about `slideToggle(100)`? And How to identify when the div is opened or closed?

Comment: @CésarNontol Yeah, so `slideToggle()` will show your element by "sliding" down and up depending on what state it is currently in (hidden or shown). the `100` is simply the speed (1000 being a second). If is a div is hidden, it's closed. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the element to the DOM before setting up your click event handlers. See the reordered JavaScript below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var code = '<p class="click-me">Click Me!</p>';     
    var divToShow = document.getElementById('toShow');
    var clickMeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('click-me'); // Here is the problem
    var isOpenedClass = 'isOpened';
    var formIsClosed = true;
    $('#container').append(code);   //moved up this line

    $(clickMeDiv).click(function() {
        $(divToShow).toggleClass(isOpenedClass);
        formIsClosed = false;
    });
    $(clickMeDiv).click(function() {
        if (formIsClosed) {
            $(divToShow).removeClass(isOpenedClass);
        }
        formIsClosed = true;
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it. The problem was in the order of the functions.